# Controlling access to loading of a JAVA class at runtime

Tags: java, access-control, code-access-security

I have a requirement to restrict access to loading of a particular class of a JAVA application, at runtime. Just wondering whether this is possible using JAVA Security Manager with a security policy. Also, if this is a possibility, I'd like to know how the permission configuration would look like in a JAVA security policy. I'd done some researching on this but couldn't really find any useful solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

These two:

java.security.Permission
java.io.FilePermission

and providing you need to continue the application operating in some way without it you need to load classes using java.lang.ClassLoader and loadClass method to be able to throw it into an if-else to bypass potentially if simple instantiation is not involved.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with a custom permission implementation extending java.security.RuntimePermission class and get my requirement fulfilled. The only overhead (which is unavoidable) associated with the approach of introducing a custom permission is that, you need to hack into all your classloading implementations and add an additional check to evaluate your custom permission.